# In ngIf how to check if array key exists?

Tags: angular

`files` is the array of objects. It always has name property but it may or may not have progress property. Progress has a value of type number. Is there a way to check if progress exists in the `ngIf`:-

```
<tr *ngFor="let file of files; let i=index;">
  <td>{{file.name}}</td>
  <td *ngIf="file.progress"> Show This if progress doesnt exist</td>
  <td *ngIf="file.progress"> Show This if progress exists</td>
<tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this. you can use `<ng-template>` and implement the else condition. so there is not need to implement the `*ngIf` twice.

```
 <tr *ngFor="let file of files; let i=index;">
    <td>{{file.name}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="file?.progress; else elsePart"> Show This if progress doesnt exist</td>
    <ng-template #elsePart>
    <td> Show This if progress exists</td>
    </ng-template>
 <tr>
```

Comment: It will not work if `file` has `progress` property with a falsy value..! :) Like `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: Yupppp :) I just modified the ans if we use ternary operator then it will work. no need to use  `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: Still, it will show the first condition if the `file.progress` has `null` or `''` value. Question is to check that object has property or not, it's not about checking falsy values..!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [Object​.prototype​.has​OwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method to check if the file object has property `progress`:-

```
<tr *ngFor="let file of files; let i=index;">
    <td>{{file.name}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="!file.hasOwnProperty('progress')">Show This if progress doesnt exist</td>
    <td *ngIf="file.hasOwnProperty('progress')">Show This if progress exists</td>
<tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this

```html
<tr *ngFor="let file of files; let i=index;">
    <td>{{file.name}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="file.progress.length === 0"> Show This if progress doesnt exist</td>
    <td *ngIf="file.progress.length > 0"> Show This if progress exists</td>
<tr>
```

Make sure that the array format is like below format and the progress is a string.

```js
const files = [
  {
    name: 'ram',
    progress: 'jhsdgfshgdfjhsgdfg',
  },
  {
    name: 'ramdfgdrf',
    progress: '',
  },
  {
    name: 'ramdfg',
    progress: 'shgdfjhsgdfg',
  },
  {
    name: 'rdsfgdam',
    progress: 'hgdfjhsgdfg',
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr *ngFor="let file of files; let i=index;">
    <td>{{file.name}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="!file['progress']">Show This if progress doesnt exist</td>
    <td *ngIf="file['progress']">Show This if progress exists</td>
<tr>
```

I would try to access the attribute, if not exists then it will return undefined and thus false.